# Android two way data binding with onclick() not working

Tags: android, onclick, android-databinding

I am trying to implement android two way databinding in my code. I am not able get onclick event for a textview which I have used for two way data binding for its text.

**ps:**

1. I have enabled data binding
2. I have set all the variable to binding as well

### layout xml

```
        <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/likes"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="@{clickHandler::onClickEvents}"
                    android:text='@= 
 {com.coffeeshots.app.foodieapp.utils.Converter.convertIntToString(food.likes)}'
     </TextView>
```

`

### databinding code

```
<data>
    <variable 
       name="food" 
       type="com.coffeeshots.app.foodieapp.model.Food"/>

    <import type="com.coffeeshots.app.foodieapp.utils.Converter"/>
   
    <variable 
       name="clickHandler" 
       type="com.coffeeshots.app.foodieapp.utils.ClickHandler"/>
</data>
```

### onclick method

```
 public void onClickEvents(View view) {

          switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.likes:
                if(!likesGiven){
                    likesGiven = true;
                    binding.likes.setText("1");
                    binding.dislikes.setClickable(false);
             }
                break;

          }
```

I think the problem is the way i inflate the layout, Can anyone help me here ???

```
  LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

     binding= DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater,R.layout.activity_add_food,null,false);
    
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

Comment: Have you add 
`dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }` . in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: yes, Is there any issue using two way binding with text and setting onclick listener together for a view

Comment: Did you tried setting ClickHandler instance to your binding object? Something like; binding.setClickHandler(new ClickHandler())

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
android:onClick="@{(view)-> clickHandler.onClickEvents(view)}"
```

Comment: what will be view here?

Comment: view object will contain the parameters of Textview

Comment: are you calling binding.setClickHandler(new ClickHandler()); ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your layout inflating is wrong. Do like this:

```
ActivityAddFoodBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_add_food);
binding.setClickHandler(new ClickHandler());
```

You can also find the related official example here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#binding_data